# Dell N2024 Inter vlan routing

Tags: powerconnect

I've just bought a switch dell N2024. I have some trouble with inter-vlan routing. basically , i have two vlan, with an interface in each and an ip address configured. I'm not able to ping from a vlan to the other.

Is the switch Dell N2024 able to route betwen the vlan ?

Comment: Have you enabled ip routing?
type "ip routing" in global config

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Never having worked on one, I took a look at the documentation and would have to say that yes it can, at least in some limited fashion.

Based on the [spec sheet](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell_Networking_N2000_Series_SpecSheet_EN_1_0.pdf) for this product line, it would seem to indicate it can as it supports static routes, dynamic routes, and specifies "Line-rate Layer 3 routing" as well as the number of RIP and VLAN routing interfaces.

Both the [User Configuration Guide](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_networking/esuprt_net_fxd_prt_swtchs/networking-n2000-series_Deployment%20Guide9_en-us.pdf) and the [CLI Reference Guide](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_networking/esuprt_net_fxd_prt_swtchs/networking-n2000-series_Deployment%20Guide3_en-us.pdf) seem to provide the information needed to configure routing.

However, it is marketed as a L2 or L2+ switch rather than a L3 switch.  It doesn't support OSPF and is limited in the number of routes it can handle.  In the [Dell Networking Product Portfolio Guide](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell_Networking_Quick_Reference_Guide.pdf), it indicates the N2000 series switches are not meant as aggregation/L3 switches.

So while it appears to have the functionality, the features and possibly the performance may not meet the expectations of a modern network.

Comment: You are absolutely right (I have a bunch of these in use).
In case Pouilly wants to try it whatsoever, "ip routing", dropped in the CLI in configuration mode should enable the routing capabilities of the device.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. This white paper describes how to use ACLs and routing maps handle inter-VLAN traffic in a more secure way.

https://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/04/shared-content~data-sheets~en/documents~dell_networking_n_series_policy_based_routing_pbr.pdf